# Bootstrap input value only displaying the first word

Tags: php, mysql, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my website I am echoing some data to an edit-page. On this page I have Bootstrap input's echoing out from MySQL. The damnest thing is that only the first word is displayed. I could go for a textarea, but that doesn't match the layout.

PDO (after login):

```
    $getid = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM db WHERE testid=:testid');
    $getid->bindParam(':testid', $_GET['testid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result = $getid->execute();
    $row = $getid->fetch();
```

The column with the data I'm struggling with is varchar(300).

HTML

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" <?php echo "value=" . $row['info']; ?>>
```

The column has 10-15 words, but only the first is displayed, anybody know why? If this is a HTML5 Input issue, can it be tweaked to display all words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" value="<?php echo $row['info']; ?>">
```

The issue is that you're not closing your `value` with quotes in the PHP code.

The way you wrote the code, to work, should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" <?php echo "value=\"" . $row['info'] . "\""; ?>>
```

Notice the escaped `\"` double quotes echoed before and after your sentence.

Edit:: to further explain why the unexpected behavior you're getting, take a look at the HTML code that would be printed when you run that PHP page. It will look something like this. Notice how even on SO syntax colors, only the word "the" becomes blue in the first example, while the full sentence becomes blue in the second.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" value=the words inside info>
```

Because you're not using XHTML, the syntax error will be "fixed" by assuming only the first word is the value. The rest of the words will be ignored or considered other undefined attributes. The way it should look is obviously

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="info" value="the words inside info">
```

So you can fix that by either adding the quotes in HTML or by printing them in the PHP code.

Comment: Ah, the little things. Funny how one goes blind after a few hours of programing. Thank you for helping me out @aron9forever, much appreciated!